# Perl : How to store line by line of a file in an array and read only last 4 lines of the array

Tags: perl

Perl : How to store line by line of a file in an array and read only last 4 lines of the array .

Now I want to compare with few values to the last 4 values of the array  .

Comment: `my @array = <$filehandle>;` would read all lines from the open file. `$array[-1]` gives you the last line in the array. I think you got the rest.

Comment: @Siphali Please make sure you paste code also( which you tried). This would help people to find/answer what problem you're facing with respect to the script.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to read the entire file into an array:

```
use feature qw( say );
my @text = do { local @ARGV = $file ; <> };
say "@text[-4 .. -1]";               # last 4 lines of the array
say "@text[($#text-3) .. $#text]";   # same
say $text[-1];                       # last line of the file
say $text[-4];                       # 4th line from the end of the file
```